# Java unit converter GUI application

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, converters, jcombobox

I'm trying to make a simple unit Mass conversion GUI application. I have two combo boxes to select units from, an input box to input a number to convert, and text to display the result of the conversion.

My problem right now is that I'm trying to get the actual push of the button to initiate the calculations, but instead it's getting initiated when I select anything from the `list` dropdown combobox. I could enter a number into the textbox, select a unit from the 2nd combo box, and then select something from the first combo box, and it will work because it has the variables it needs.

My code is right below.

```
public class GuiApp{
  JFrame frame;
  JButton button;
  JTextField field;
  JLabel prompt,result,to;
  JPanel contentpane;
  JComboBox list,list2;

  public GuiApp(){
    frame = new JFrame("Mass Conversion Application");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentpane=new JPanel();
    contentpane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
    String [] type={"Units", "Gram(s)","Kilogram(s)", "Pound(s)","Ounce(s)"};
    list=new JComboBox(type);
    list.setAlignmentX(JComboBox.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
    list.addActionListener(new converty());
    contentpane.add(list);
    to=new JLabel("to");
    contentpane.add(to);
    list2=new JComboBox(type);
    list2.setAlignmentX(JComboBox.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    list2.setSelectedIndex(0);   
    list2.addActionListener(new converty());
    contentpane.add(list2);
    prompt=new JLabel("Enter here:");
    prompt.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    contentpane.add(prompt);
    field=new JTextField(10);
    contentpane.add(field);
    button=new JButton("Convert");
    button.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button.setEnabled(false);
    button.addActionListener(new converty());
    button.setActionCommand("Convert");
    contentpane.add(button);     
    result=new JLabel(" asdff ");
    result.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    contentpane.add(result);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setContentPane(contentpane); 
  }

  class converty implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){    
      if (!list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Units") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Units")){
        button.setEnabled(true);
      }
      if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list2.getSelectedItem().toString()) && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+thing+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
      else if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Gram(s)") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Kilogram(s)") && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+(thing/1000)+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());             
      }
      else if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Gram(s)") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pound(s)") && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+(thing*453.59237)+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
      else if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Gram(s)") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Ounce(s)") && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+(thing*28.349523125)+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
      else if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Kilogram(s)") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Gram(s)") && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+(thing*1000)+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
      else if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Kilogram(s)") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pound(s)") && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+(thing/0.45359237)+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
      else if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Kilogram(s)") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Ounce(s)") && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+(thing/0.0283495231257)+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
      else if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Ounce(s)") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Gram(s)") && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+(thing*28.349523125)+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());    
      }   
      else if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Ounce(s)") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pound(s)") && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+(thing/0.0625)+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
      else if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Ounce(s)") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Kilogram(s)") && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+(thing/0.0625)+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
      else if (list.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Ounce(s)") && !list2.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Pound(s)") && button.getActionCommand().equals("Convert")){
        double thing=Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
        result.setText(thing+" "+list.getSelectedItem().toString()+" is equal to "+(thing/0.0625)+" "+list2.getSelectedItem().toString());
      }
    }

  }

  private static void GuiApp(){
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    GuiApp greeting= new GuiApp();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      public void run() {  
        GuiApp();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to have the action listener on both lists and the button. Instead, just have it on the button.

The way you have it, the calculation will be performed every time either of the lists is changes (as you've observed). If it's just on the button, it will only be called when the button is clicked.

Comment: When I remove the actionlisteners from my lists none of the if else statements work, even my first one that enables the button

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't think I read your code fully before posting my answer.